# Personally identifiable information (PII) safeguard while exporting case data

Tags: data-export, gdpr

I have a requirement where a customer will export their case data however, they also want to remove/mask any PII data from the case export.

All that I have read on this topic is platform encryption or data masking for sandbox etc. This will not work for a data export if I understand.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?
Can this be done in a data export or data loader perhaps?

I am also thinking if not possible in the export then is there a way to run some job on a csv file that will achieve this? Any excel tools/tips here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just exclude those columns from the export?

Comment: Sure, but what if the data is contained within the subject and description fields which are pretty critical.

Comment: Create shadow fields for subject and description and mask sensitive bits using apex code.  You'll need to mass update all existing records though.  Then export the shadow fields

Comment: I dont think that will work since this is the customer's instance. I will have to ask them to do this in production, do not think they will agree to this. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Post process the CSV file then by a trusted user.  Repost this question on the Excel forum(s)

Comment: Have you looked into using Pattern and Matcher classes in Case Trigger to identify PII in the fields you plan on returning/making visible to the customer, and when a match is found handle it appropriately? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_example.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 - Add shadow fields to Case**

- Case.Description_Masked__c
- Case.Subject_Masked__c

Write an Apex trigger on Case to copy/mask values from the OOTB fields to the xxx_Masked__c fields.  You will most likely need to use regex (Pattern and Matcher classes as suggested by @MaxGoldfarb above)

You will also need to apply this trigger to all existing records to create masked values

- Then, use Data Loader or Reports to export the masked fields in lieu of the OOTB fields

**Option 2**

If you are unable to add new fields / trigger to the Case object as you indicated in the comments:

- Use a trusted user to export the unmasked data to Excel
- Apply excel formulas or VBA to the unmasked fields to create masked values (consult excel forums for best way to do this given your specifics)
- delete the columns for the unmasked data
- rinse and repeat every time you need to export